# Check if is there any duplicate values in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `Table` with multiple `rows` and in each row there are some input fields and i want check if there is  `Duplicates value` in table.

Here is my code , first I'm trying to find if is there any empty value , how can I check if is there any duplicates value too?

JavaScript:

```
<script>
 var isValid;
    function Step2Validation(e) {
        $(".trtickets").each(function () {

            var FindName = $(this).find(".navn");
            var FindLastName = $(this).find(".efternavn");

            if (FindName.val() == "") {
                isValid = false;
                alert("Empty Name");
                return false;
            }
            if (FindLastName.val() == "") {
                isValid = false;
                alert("Empty Lastname");
                return false;
            }

            else {
                $(e).closest('fieldset').slideUp().next().slideDown();

            }

        });
    }

    function step2(e) {

        Step2Validation(e);

    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <tr class="trtickets">
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="model.RegistrationLists[0].Name" value="John" class="form-control navn" placeholder="Name">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="model.RegistrationLists[0].Lastname" class="form-control efternavn" placeholder="Lastname">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="trtickets">
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="model.RegistrationLists[1].Name" value="John" class="form-control navn" placeholder="Name">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="model.RegistrationLists[1].Lastname" class="form-control efternavn" placeholder="Lastname">
  </td>
</tr>

   <button type="button" onclick="step2(this);" class="step2">Next</button>
```

Comment: `$(".trtickets").not(this)` to get all the rows that are not the one you are currently validating.  From there you can find the elements you want, map their values to an array, and check that array to see if any of the values match your own.  If they do, boom, duplicate.

Comment: @Taplar if you dont mind , would you please give me an example :) i tried wat you said but no lock :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest avoiding the `alert()` as it causes the browser to freeze.  Instead, consider adding the error message to the page as a displayable.

```js
var isValid = false;

function findDuplicates ($elements, selector) {
                    // filter to just the elements that match the selector
  var valueGroups = $elements.filter(selector).get()
    // reduce to elements to a map consisting of a key being their input value
    // and the map value being an array of elements with that input value
    .reduce(function(elementsByValue, element){
      var value = element.value.trim();
      
      // if we do not have a value, ignore as these will already have an
      // error of Entry required
      if (value) {
        elementsByValue[value] = elementsByValue[value] || [];
        elementsByValue[value].push(element);
      }
      
      return elementsByValue;
    }, {});
  
  // now that we have elements grouped by their input values, any input value
  // that is associated with multiple elements needs to mark those elements
  // as duplicates
  Object.values(valueGroups).forEach(function(group){
    if (group.length > 1) {
      $(group).next('.message').addClass('error').text('Duplicate value');
    }
  });
}

function Step2Validation (e) {
  // find all the inputs
  var $requiredInputs = $('.trtickets').find('.navn, .efternavn');
  
  // find all the inputs that previously had errors, remove the errors
  $requiredInputs.next('.message.error')
    .removeClass('error').html('&nbsp;');
  
  $requiredInputs
    // filter to just the elements without a value
    .filter(function(){ return !this.value.trim(); })
    // go to each one of the empty inputs next message element
    .next('.message')
    // add the error class
    .addClass('error')
    // add the error text
    .text('Entry required');
  
  // find duplicates in each separate group
  findDuplicates($requiredInputs, '.navn');
  findDuplicates($requiredInputs, '.efternavn');
  
  // if any of the messages has the error class, it is not valid
  isValid = $requiredInputs.next('.message.error').length < 1;
  
  if (isValid) {
    $(e.target).closest('fieldset').slideUp().next().slideDown();
  }
}

$('.step2').on('click', Step2Validation);
```

```css
.message.error { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Tickettbl" class="table">
  <tbody id="output">
    <tr class="trtickets">
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="model.RegistrationLists[0].Name" class="form-control navn" placeholder="Name">
        <div class="message">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="model.RegistrationLists[0].Lastname" class="form-control efternavn" placeholder="Lastname">
        <div class="message">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trtickets">
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="model.RegistrationLists[1].Name" class="form-control navn" placeholder="Name">
        <div class="message">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="model.RegistrationLists[1].Lastname" class="form-control efternavn" placeholder="Lastname">
        <div class="message">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" class="step2">Next</button>
```

Comment: Thanks :) my question it was how to find Duplicates value in Name or in Lastname. I update my question with example :)